# How to change CSS properties back AFTER click?

Tags: jquery, css

### What is happening

[image]

As you can see, the Add button works fine before I click the Remove button. After I click the Remove button, the Add button stays the same color.

***What I would like to happen*** is for the Add button reverts to its old color.

I think the reason its doing this is because in my jQuery I change the colors, but I never change them back after the click is over.

If someone could help me with this I would really appreciated it!

### My code

*HTML*

```
<div class="worksheet-problems">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-lg worksheet-problem">
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-bullet"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-one-fine-dot" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="Worksheet-Problem" class="form-control" placeholder="Problem..." aria-label="Write worksheet problem here">
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-add" aria-label="Add"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

*CSS*

```
/*get rid of grey shadow when press on buttons*/
.btn.button-add, .btn.button-bullet, .btn.button-bullet:active, .btn.button-add:active, .btn.button-add:focus, 
.btn.button-bullet:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

/*get rid of Boostrap default grey for buttons*/
.btn.button-add, .btn.button-bullet {
  background-color: transparent;

}

.btn.button-add:hover, #Done-Button:hover{
    background-color: #E5FFFB;
}

.glyphicon-plus-sign, .glyphicon-ok-sign{
    color: #02C8A7;
}
```

*jQuery*

```
$(".worksheet-problems").on("click", ".button-add", function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#02C8A7");
    $(this).children(".glyphicon").css("color", "#E5FFFB");
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/py1q2y37/)

### UPDATE

I realized that the glitch is not because I click the Remove button. It's because when I click the Add button, I change the color of that Add button and also clone it to become the next Problem row.

So though these answers change the color of the Add button when the Remove button is clicked, I realize I need something that changes the Add button back after it is cloned to the next row.

Is there some way to delay reverting the Add button color back for half a second? I'm trying to use delay but I don't think I'm using it correctly because nothing is happening.

*Updated jQuery*

```
$(".worksheet-problems").on("click", ".button-add", function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
    var $wsProbRow = $row.clone(true);
    $wsProbRow.find("input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']").val("");
    $wsProbRow.insertAfter($row);
    $(this).css("background-color", "#02C8A7");
    $(this).children(".glyphicon").css("color", "#E5FFFB").delay(500).queue(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
        $(this).children(".glyphicon").css("color", "#02C8A7");
    });
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/py1q2y37/3/)

Comment: a small doubt why do you change the background-color via jQuery? what is the purpose of changing the color?

Comment: Make your change a class and then use "toggle" to add and remove that class on click. Then you can do whatever you want to the "this" element clicked. This also means you check for the class instead of checking to see if the children with the inline style exists or not.

Comment: Can you specify what buttons you want to have a dark blue color and what buttons light blue?

Comment: @vinayakj it's because I want the glypicon to change color when the Add-button is clicked and I don't think I can do that in CSS

Comment: @15ongm - you _can_ do that in CSS, add/remove (toggle) a class when the button is clicked as Nathaniel suggests; a class like "clicked" or "active" or something _descriptive_. Per your _UPDATE_ — when cloning, don't clone a "live" control; have a "prototype" add button that is kept off-page and clone _that_, —or— clone the add-button immediately on page load and hold onto that clone in javascript (don't add it to the DOM anywhere), then clone _that_ (clone the first clone) as it will never change state.

Comment: @StephenP I know there are pseudo-selectors in CSS such as "clicked" or "active". The thing is, the glyphicon are nested inside my buttons. So if I used CSS, (i.e. `.glyphicon:clicked`), only when I click the glyphicon in the button will the glypicon change. If I click the button and not the glyphicon, then the glyphicon will not change, and that is not what I want.

Comment: @StephenP But I am interested in your suggestion to clone a prototype. How would I go about that exactly? I'm asking because I've had struggles trying to copy huge amounts of HTML into JavaScript and that's why I opted to use cloning instead.

Comment: @15ongm There's way too much to go into here in comments. Search for `"web components"` and for `"shadow dom"`.  Since old browsers may not support enough to do that, the basic idea is to have a HTML element, probably `display:none`, the root of some possibly complex structure, that you `.detach()` from the page and keep a reference to. You can then clone and `.append()` that structure multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update your remove button code to below, to reverse the color changes just only for last row.

```
$(".worksheet-problems").on("click", ".button-bullet", function() {
    if ($(".worksheet-problems").children().length > 1) {
      //reverse color changes to last row
      $(this).closest('.worksheet-problems .row').last().find(".button-add")
             .css("background-color", "")
             .children(".glyphicon").css("color", "");
      //remove current row
      $(this).closest('.row').remove();

    }
  });
```

**UPDATE**

After your update to question now I got your problem use below snippets & complete example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // have the html reay with you & when needed insert into DOM
  var wsProbRow = $('.worksheet-problems .row')[0].outerHTML;
```

update add function to below

```
 $(".worksheet-problems").on("click", ".button-add", function() {
    $(this).closest(".worksheet-problems").append($(wsProbRow));
  });
```

See below the working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wsProbRow = $('.worksheet-problems .row')[0].outerHTML;
  
  $(".worksheet-problems").on("mouseenter", ".form-group", function() {
    $(this).find(".button-add").fadeIn(100);
    if ($(".worksheet-problems").children().length > 1) {
      $(this).find(".button-bullet").children(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-one-fine-dot");
      $(this).find(".button-bullet").children(".glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-minus-sign");
    }
  });
  $(".worksheet-problems").on("mouseleave", ".form-group", function() {
    $(this).find(".button-add").fadeOut(100);
    if ($(".worksheet-problems").children().length > 1) {
      $(this).find(".button-bullet").children(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-minus-sign");
      $(this).find(".button-bullet").children(".glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-one-fine-dot");
    }
  });

  $(".worksheet-problems").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".button-bullet", function() {
    if ($(".worksheet-problems").children().length > 1) {
      $(this).toggleClass("light-red-background");
    }
  });
  $(".worksheet-problems").on("click", ".button-add", function() {
    $(this).closest(".worksheet-problems").append($(wsProbRow));
  });

  $(".worksheet-problems").on("click", ".button-add", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#02C8A7");
    $(this).children(".glyphicon").css("color", "#E5FFFB");
  });

  $(".worksheet-problems").on("click", ".button-bullet", function() {
    if ($(".worksheet-problems").children().length > 1) {
      
      $(this).closest('.row').remove();

    }
  });

  $(".worksheet-problems").on("click active focus", ".button-bullet", function() {
    if ($(".worksheet-problems").children().length > 1) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "#F53240");
      $(this).children(".glyphicon").css("color", "#FCC1C5");
    } else {
      $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
    }
  });

})
```

```css
/*import custom font*/

@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900';
.container-fluid {
  background-color: #86E1D8;
}


/*Page*/

.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  /*Background shadow*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 13px 3px rgba(155, 155, 155, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 13px 3px rgba(155, 155, 155, 1);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 13px 3px rgba(155, 155, 155, 1);
}


/*remove header grey line*/

.page-header {
  border-bottom: none;
}


/*Get rid of that blue outline when input text*/


/*.form-control{
    border: none;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}*/


/*Get rid of blue outline Chrome*/

.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
}


/*Buttons*/

.button-add {
  display: none;
}

#Done-Button {
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}


/*get rid of grey shadow when press on buttons*/

.btn.button-add,
.btn.button-bullet,
.btn.button-bullet:active,
.btn.button-add:active,
.btn.button-add:focus,
.btn.button-bullet:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}


/*get rid of Boostrap default grey for buttons*/

.btn.button-add,
.btn.button-bullet {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn.button-add:hover,
#Done-Button:hover {
  background-color: #E5FFFB;
}

.btn.light-red-background {
  background-color: #FCC1C5;
}

.glyphicon-minus-sign,
.glyphicon-plus-sign {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.glyphicon-minus-sign {
  color: #F53240;
}

.glyphicon-plus-sign,
.glyphicon-ok-sign {
  color: #02C8A7;
}

.glyphicon-ok-sign {
  font-size: 70px;
}


/*Circle icon*/

.glyphicon.glyphicon-one-fine-dot {
  margin-top: -1.4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-one-fine-dot:before {
  content: "\25cf";
  font-size: 3em;
}


/*Circular buttons*/

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.btn-circle.btn-lg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 35px;
}


/*Add borders when hover or click on input boxes*/

input[type="text"] {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: 1px solid white;
  /*make the borders invisble by turning same color as background*/
}

input[type="text"]:hover,
input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
}


/*Style input text boxes*/

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name'] {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem'] {
  font-size: 20px;
}


/*Change placeholder*/

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name']::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 36px;
}

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name']::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 36px;
}

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name']:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 36px;
}

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name']:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 36px;
}


/*Change placeholder*/

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="row page-header">
          <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="Worksheet-Name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Worksheet Name..." aria-label="Write worksheet name here"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="worksheet-problems">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg worksheet-problem">
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-bullet"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-one-fine-dot" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" name="Worksheet-Problem" class="form-control" placeholder="Problem..." aria-label="Write worksheet problem here">
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-add" aria-label="Add"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <a id="Done-Button" href="Demo.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: hmm I do like your answer; the only thing is after you click the Add button, the Add button stays the same color (dark green on outside, light green plus). Is there a way to revert the Add button back (light green on outside, dark green plus) after you click it?

Comment: thats what was the previous answer, but you said thats not the requirement. Please try to combine above to answers to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code with the following changes:

Added a class called '.button-selected' to the button once the button was selected (so we can keep track of which buttons have been selected)

```
$(".worksheet-problems").on("click", ".button-add", function(){
     $(this).addClass('button-selected');
});
```

When the '.button-bullet' is selected, I remove 'button-selected' from the previous row's button

```
$(".worksheet-problems").on("click", ".button-bullet", function () {
    var previousRow = $(this).closest('.row').prev();
    previousRow.find('.button-selected').removeClass('button-selected');

    if ($(".worksheet-problems").children().length > 1) {
        $(this).closest('.row').remove();
    }
});
```

I also added a few lines of CSS to handle the new class addition 'button-selected'

```
.btn.button-add.button-selected{
  background-color: rgb(2, 200, 167);
}

.glyphicon-plus-sign{
  color: #02C8A7;
}

.button-selected .glyphicon-plus-sign{
  color: #E5FFFB;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle with working code

https://jsfiddle.net/iamnottony/q64280L4/4/